# Are lacquer re-coats supposed to dissolve/remove pinhole bubbles?

Tags: finishing, wood-repair, hardwood

I am brushing lacquer on 50 small walnut plates. My first coats were a bit of a learning curve and I had produced some small bubbles.

My understanding is that new coats of lacquer will dissolve into the previous coats fixing small imperfections. After my 2nd coat of Watco's clear finish dried for 2 hours (as label recommended), I applied my 3rd and anticipated final coat. No new bubbles, but the previous ones are still present.

Aren't lacquer re-coats supposed to dissolve/remove pinhole bubbles?

To remedy this, I'm trying to decide the best course of action. Should I:

1. Sand with 400 grit and apply another coat
2. Rub out and see if its enough
3. Apply a bit of lacquer thinner +/- lacquer and re-coat

Comment: 50+ years ago when some cars had lacquer paint; a friend who had a body and fender shop would put on a final spray of lacquer thinner . This developed a good gloss so buffing could be skipped. Some times it make "orange peel" finish.